# Unexpected result of assembly program

Tags: assembly, interrupt, masm, cpu-registers

I have just started learning assembly language and I am following this [tutorial](http://www.skynet.ie/~darkstar/assembler/tut1.html).

**I have written the following program:**

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
    msg db "123123.$"
.CODE
MAIN PROC

    MOV AH,02   ; Function to output a char
    MOV DL,"!"      ; Character to output
    INT 21h     ; Call the interrupt to output "!"

    MOV AH, 09
    MOV DX, OFFSET msg
    INT 21h

    MOV AH,04Ch ; Select exit function
    MOV AL,00   ; Return 0
    INT 21h     ; Call

MAIN ENDP           ; Terminate program
END MAIN
```

I am expecting the following output:

```
! 123123
```

But I am getting the following:

[image]

- Register `AH` is used to store the sub-function.
- Register `DL` is used for storing character to output using `INT 21h`
- Register `DX` is used for storing the address of string to print using `INT 21h`

## Questions:

1.) Are the above points right? If not, what am I not getting right?

2.) If the above points are right then why am I getting unexpected output?

3.) How to avoid this kind of behavior in the future?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tutorial deals with `.MODEL TINY` to produce a `.com`-executable. You use `.MODEL SMALL` and produce an `.exe`-executable. For `.MODEL SMALL` you must explicitely set the `DS`-register which points by default to the PSP (not to `.DATA`):

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 1000H    ; Mor stack, less trouble
.DATA
    msg db "123123.$"
.CODE
MAIN PROC
    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX

... (no change) ...
```

Comment: Thank you sir it worked. Can your provide me a link to where I can read more about this `.MODEL TINY` and `.MODEL SMALL`.

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi: Google for "turbo assembler users guide pdf" and download the user's guide. TASM is very similar to MASM.